# Can positive values with sd > mean have skewness = 0?

Tags: distributions, skewness, moments, probability-inequalities

I'm trying to create an example of a distribution with all positive values, standard deviation > mean, and skewness =0 (third moment). I cannot. Is that possible? Can you prove it mathematically? Thanks.

Comment: @MattF. Thank you. Quite right. I misread. Comment deleted. A much more interesting question.

Comment: @GabyLP when you say "skewness" do you mean third moment skewness -, that is $E[(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma})^3]$ - or some other skewness measure like second Pearson skewness, Bowley skewness, etc?

Comment: third moment @Glen_b

Comment: Can we prove this using Holder’s inequality? This reminds me of https://mathoverflow.net/a/278189

Comment: @Matt Holder's Inequality concerns *absolute* moments.  Thus, although it can be helpful, it will not directly make the demonstration.

Comment: @whuber, I know, but take some inspiration from the answer I linked to!

Comment: I suspect the nearest you can get is $X=k$ or $0$ each with probability $\frac12$ (so non-negative rather than positive) which has zero skewness (symmetric about the mean) with standard deviation equal to the mean of $\frac k2$ (i.e. not strictly greater)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is impossible. Suppose $X$ is the distribution, and let $a,b,c$ be its first three moments, $a=E[X], b=E[X^2], c=E[X^3]$.

We derive three relationships for these variables, and show that they can not be satisfied simulateously.

First, by the [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory) inequality:
\begin{align}
E[\sqrt{X^\phantom{1}}\!\! \sqrt{X^3}] &\le \sqrt{E[X]}\sqrt{E[X^3]}\\
(E[X^2])^2 &\le E[X]E[X^3]\\
b^2 &\le ac \\
\end{align}
where $\sqrt{X}$ and $\sqrt{X^3}$ are positive by the positivity of $X$.

Second, since skewness is 0,
\begin{align}
\phantom{skewness = skewness = = = }0 &= E[(X-a)^3]\\
&= E[X^3]-3aE[X^2]+3a^2E[X]-a^3\\
&= c-3ab+3a^3-a^3\\
&= c-3ab+2a^3
\end{align}

Third, since the standard deviation is greater than the mean,
\begin{align}
\text{variance} &> \text{mean}^2 \phantom{+mean} \\
b - a^2 &> a^2\\
b &> 2a^2\\
\end{align}
and, since $a^2$ is positive, also $b>a^2$.

Together these yield
$$0\ge b^2-ac=(b-2a^2)(b-a^2)>0$$
which is impossible.